# What the difference between availability and opportunity?

Tags: nouns

Difference between availability and opportunity?

Comment: We can provide you with more tailored and insightful answers if you include information such as research you've already done and the context in which you've heard or are using the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition of availability**

1 : the quality or state of being available trying to improve the availability of affordable housing

2 : an available person or thing

3 US : a usually brief session in which a public figure (such as a politician) is made available to answer questions from members of the press a press availability

**Definition of opportunity**

1 : a favorable juncture of circumstances the halt provided an opportunity for rest and refreshment

2 : a good chance for advancement or progress

*Source: Merriam Webster*